# UI freezes while modifying the view during animation Android

Tags: android, listview, android-animation, android-imageview

I am using transition animation to animate my ListView from bottom to top.
Each ListView element has one ImageView. Images will be loaded to ImageView after fetching the image from the web using AsyncTasks.

The problem is ListView animation works perfectly when I load the image before animation starts or after animation ends. But when I try to load the image during animation UI freezes.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: http://blog.danlew.net/2015/10/20/using-hardware-layers-to-improve-animation-performance/